# Mvvmlight UpdateSourceTrigger not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ProdcutCellEditCmd,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"></cmd:EventToCommand>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding id}" Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ParentLCSKU}" Header="LCSKU(Parent)" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ChildLCSKU}" Header="LCSKU(Child)" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductColors}}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Color}" Header="颜色" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductSizes}}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Size}" Header="尺寸" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductCategories}}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Category}" Header="类别" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cost}" Header="成本"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsOEM,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="OEM"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

viewmodel

```
public ProductVM()
{
    ProdcutCellEditCmd = new RelayCommand<DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs>(prodcutDataGridCellEditEnding);

}
public RelayCommand<DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs> ProdcutCellEditCmd { get; set; }
private void prodcutDataGridCellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {
        var prodcut = e.Row.DataContext as BaseProduct;
        SelectedProduct = prodcut;
        productSave();
    }
}
```

I want to trigger the CellEditEnding event after the checkbox be checked or unchecked, but this event only fires when the cell lost focus.

Whats wrong with this?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal behavior cause event name is `CellEditEnding`. It means that event is fired after finish of cell edit.

I suggest you to bind to `Command` property in `CheckBox`. 
If you `DataGrid` placed in `Window`, you should write:

```
<CheckBox Header="OEM" IsChecked="{Binding IsOEM,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}}"
                 Command="{Binding DataContext.ProdcutCellEditCmd, RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}}"}" />
```

If you `DataGrid` placed in `UserControl`, you should write:

```
<CheckBox Header="OEM" IsChecked="{Binding IsOEM,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}}"
                 Command="{Binding DataContext.ProdcutCellEditCmd, RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}"}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing in that case you have to update code like

First give the name of your datagrid like

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" Name="dg" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}">
```

Now you have to bind the Checkbox checked event and pass the row of datagrid so you can access all values of that rows in ViewModel

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsOEM,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="OEM">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckBoxChecked,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dg,Path=SelectedItem}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Your `RelayCommand` should be like 
I assume that you have bind the List in your datagrid so based on it your relay command should be

```
 private RelayCommand<BaseProduct> _CheckBoxChecked;

    public RelayCommand<BaseProduct> CheckBoxChecked
    {
        get { return _CheckBoxChecked??(_CheckBoxChecked=new RelayCommand<BaseProduct>(CheckMethod)); }
        set { _CheckBoxChecked = value; }
    }
    void CheckMethod(BaseProduct product)
    {
      // you can access product here 
    }
```

Comment: But where should I put the CheckBoxChecked command? The default datacontext of the DataGridCheckBoxColumn is the item from the datagrid items source, so I cant bind the VM's command to the DataGridCheckBoxColumn's event.

Comment: @zhzhwcn: no you can bind the VM's Command in DataGridCheckBoxColumn for that I have used RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dg,Path=SelectedItem}